# Apply a user-defined function that takes function as argument

Tags: r, apply, user-defined-functions

How can I "apply" a user-defined function to each row of a data frame if the user-defined function takes a function as an argument?

Here's an example... Let's say I have three columns in a data frame, each containing integers. For each row, I'd like to take the minimum integer and convert it to a corresponding letter using a lookup dataset. Similarly, perform the same task with the max integer. Result would be this:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | MaxVal | MinVal |
-------------------------------------
 1      2      1       B        A
 4      4      1       F        A
 5      6      2       F        B
```

The code below causes: `Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "MaxVal", value = integer(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 3`

```
myData <- data.frame("Col1" = c(1, 4, 5), "Col2" = c(2, 6, 6), "Col3" = c(1, 1, 2))
numberToLetterData <- data.frame("Number" = 1:6, "Letter" = c("A", "B","C","D","E","F"))

GetMinOrMaxForRow <- function(x, refData, functionToUse){
    refData$Letter[refData$Number ==  functionToUse(x)]
}

myData$MinVal <- apply(myData, 1, FUN = function(x) GetMinOrMaxForRow(x = x, refData = numberToLetterData, functionToUse = min))
myData$MaxVal <- apply(myData, 1, FUN = function(x) GetMinOrMaxForRow(x = x, refData = numberToLetterData, functionToUse = max))
```

...but the following code (with the last two lines switched) works fine:

```
myData <- data.frame("Col1" = c(1, 4, 5), "Col2" = c(2, 6, 6), "Col3" = c(1, 1, 2))
numberToLetterData <- data.frame("Number" = 1:6, "Letter" = c("A", "B","C","D","E","F"))

GetMinOrMaxForRow <- function(x, refData, functionToUse){
    refData$Letter[refData$Number ==  functionToUse(x)]
}

myData$MaxVal <- apply(myData, 1, FUN = function(x) GetMinOrMaxForRow(x = x, refData = numberToLetterData, functionToUse = max))
myData$MinVal <- apply(myData, 1, FUN = function(x) GetMinOrMaxForRow(x = x, refData = numberToLetterData, functionToUse = min))
```

... Does anyone know why?

Comment: After calling the first line, you assign myData$MinVal. In the next line, you build the max over the complete row in your dataframe, including the new MinVal column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling the first line, you assign myData$MinVal. In the next line, you build the max over the complete row in your dataframe, including the new MinVal column.

So don't apply the function to all columns, i.e. myData[,1:3] only.

```
myData <- data.frame("Col1" = c(1, 4, 5), "Col2" = c(2, 6, 6), "Col3" = c(1, 1, 2))
numberToLetterData <- data.frame("Number" = 1:6, "Letter" = c("A", "B","C","D","E","F"))

GetMinOrMaxForRow <- function(x, refData, functionToUse){
    refData$Letter[refData$Number ==  functionToUse(x)]
}

myData$MinVal <- apply(myData[,1:3], 1, FUN = function(x) GetMinOrMaxForRow(x = x, refData = numberToLetterData, functionToUse = min))
myData$MaxVal <- apply(myData[,1:3], 1, FUN = function(x) GetMinOrMaxForRow(x = x, refData = numberToLetterData, functionToUse = max))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` you could do:

```
myData %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(minVal = lookup[min(Col1, Col2, Col3)],
         maxVal = lookup[max(Col1, Col2, Col3)])
```

Or in 2 steps, so first calculating the function and then doing the lookup:

```
myData %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(minVal = min(Col1, Col2, Col3),
         maxVal = max(Col1, Col2, Col3)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(minVal, maxVal), function(x) lookup[x])
```

Using `purrr` you can do:

```
require(purrr)
lookup <- setNames(LETTERS[1:6], 1:6)
myData %>% 
  by_row(~lookup[min(.[1:3])], .collate = "cols", .to = "minVal") %>% 
  by_row(~lookup[max(.[1:3])], .collate = "cols", .to = "maxVal")
```